# Is using an int and then incrementing it slower than doing both simultaneously?

Tags: java, c#, performance, increment, jit

I ran into some old source code recently, and I noticed a pattern like this:

```
T item = array[index];
index++;
```

Would it be faster to express it as

```
T item = array[index++];
```

? Up until recently I thought there wouldn't be a difference, since I thought it was shorthand for `index = index + 1`, so either way you would be dereferencing `index` twice. But [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/134136/161912) has made me think otherwise; instead, you would only be getting the value of `index` once.

Would this yield any difference (however small) in performance, or do modern JITs optimize this away?

Comment: For which language you want to know? Why tagged both Java and C#?

Comment: @hagrawal Because both the JVM and CLR are JITs and, to my understanding, function similarly (also, incrementing an `int` is mostly language-independent).

Comment: Your 2 code snippets is in which kind of loop - for, while ??

Comment: It is simple enough to write a benchmark program and determine their relative performance in fact.

Comment: @JamesKo Yes, both are JIT's but their optimization algorithms would be different. You may also see different machine code instructions generated in each case.

Comment: The chance of this being the bottleneck in any real application is virtually non-existing. The best way to optimize your code is to focus on the parts that actually take up the most time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most moderns langages will optimise during compile or execute time.
Simple things like this will be directly optimised during compilation.

But note your exemple is just a typo question, in the 2 cases Java will understand
`T item = array[index++];` by :

- Get the object in the index place
- Add 1 to index

That's the same thing that writting

```
T item = array[index];
index++;
```

(but not the same thing that `T item = array[++index];` that is equivalent to :

```
index++;
T item = array[index];
```

Edit: 
I can also add that's the loops are improved too, compile or execute time
For exemple in C or C++

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    t[i] = 0
}
```

will become the equivalent to

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   *(t++) = 0
}
```

To conclude, compiler and virtual machine will improve your code, think more about algorithms and data structures chosen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that it is considered bad practice to increment said integer on the same line that you do other actions.

Something like the example you've provided (`T item = array[index++];`) would optimally become something like

```
index++
T item = array[index];
```

Comment: It is indeed bad practice according to the Java Language Specification: "Code is usually clearer when each expression contains at most one side effect, as its outermost operation, and when code does not depend on exactly which exception arises as a consequence of the left-to-right evaluation of expressions." [15.7. Evaluation Order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7)